# receba a quantidade de um produto e o valor e pergunte se qur digitar mais algum produto caso sim tem que repitir o processo e depois mostrar o total

Tags: portugol

ja fiz isso mas preciso somar o total de todas as vezes que o enquanto estiver

```
    rodando programa
    {
        funcao inicio()
        {
            cadeia nome
            real val, total
            inteiro quant 
            caracter opcao = 'f'
            enquanto(opcao !='n') {
                escreva("digite o nome do produto")
                leia(nome)
                escreva("digite a quantidade do produto")
                leia(quant)
                escreva("digite o valor unitario")
                leia(val)
                total = quant * val
                escreva("O total da compra foi", total)
                escreva("deseja digitar mais algum produto? (s/n)")
                leia(opcao)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adiciona uma variável totalGeral. Dentro do enquanto totalGeral = totalGeral + total e escreve fora do enquanto

Comment: vlw cara funcionou

Comment: Tamo junto. Vou escrever a resposta para ficar registrado.

Answer (score 0):

Para fins de pesquisa.

Adicionar uma variável totalGeral que receberá a somatória de todos os totais.

```
rodando programa
    {
        funcao inicio()
        {
            cadeia nome
            real val, total, totalGeral
            inteiro quant 
            caracter opcao = 'f'
            enquanto(opcao !='n') {
                escreva("digite o nome do produto")
                leia(nome)
                escreva("digite a quantidade do produto")
                leia(quant)
                escreva("digite o valor unitario")
                leia(val)
                total = quant * val
                totalGeral = totalGeral + total
                escreva("O total da compra foi", total)
                escreva("deseja digitar mais algum produto? (s/n)")
                leia(opcao)
            }
        escreva("Soma dos totais:", totalGeral)
        }
    }
```